# How to get first (and only one) element from data.items (getJson funcion)

Tags: jquery, json

I can't find how to get the first and only element from data.items, I do not want to use foreach function since I have just one element there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this, probably :

```
var myOneItem = data.items[0];
```

This will work if

- your object was already parsed (which should be the case using getJSON as the name doesn't imply)
- there's an `items` property
- this property's value is an array

---

EDIT : from your comment it seems you need that :

```
for (var key in data) {
    var val = data[key];
}
// you can use val here
```

Comment: does not work with []. I get this error: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: This means you don't have the items property.

Comment: What if the json has just only one element? The json link is this: students.info.uaic.ro/~calin.chifan/api/compartiment/sertar/… That did not work [0]

Comment: This is how the json looks {"ob_id":10032}

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
... success: function (data) {
 var oneItem = data[0].items;
 }
```

Edit:

Here is whole code

```
$.ajax({
url: "functionURL",
type: "GET/POST",
data: {functionArgument_Name:passingArgument_name},
success: function (data) {
var oneItem = data..;
}
});
```

So if you have something like this

```
public JsonResult getOneItem(string name)
{     
 Dictionary<String, String> items= new Dictionary<string, string>();
 items.Add("items",name);
 return Json(items, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Your ajax should look something like this:

```
$.ajax({
url: "getOneItem",
type: "POST",
data: {name:"abcde"},
success: function (data) {
var oneItem = data.items;
}
});
```

Comment: What if the json has just only one element? The json link is this: http://students.info.uaic.ro/~calin.chifan/api/compartiment/sertar/obiect/add.json?nume=creioane&descriere=bunica&id_sertar=1000 That did not work [0]